# Что легче : byte или char?

Tags: c#, char, byte

Добрый день!
Нужно создать переменную для хранения одного из трёх состояний игры ( Play, Lose, Win ).
Есть возможность сделать её `byte` или `char` (0, 1, 2 или 'P', 'L', 'W' соответственно).
Если выбирать из типов, то какой меньше ударит по производительности / меньше будет жрать память?

Comment: `enum` так понятнее в коде будет. И это важнее

Comment: В .Net int обычно производительнее остальных типов, поэтому лучше использовать его. А с точки зрения читаемости - используйте enum, как вам написали выше

Comment: enum хранит в себе сразу несколько цифровых значений с оригинальными именами, я правильно понял?

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, но какие-то странные у вас состояния игры. В моём понимании состоянием должно быть что-то вроде "in progress" или "finished", а "lose" и "win" - это результат матча, а не состояние. В таком случае можно было бы хранить всё в boolean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По занимаемому месту

`byte` - занимает 8 бит,

`char` - 16 бит, так как хранит символ Юникода (16-разрядный),

Это без учёта оптимизации. Если смотреть с учётом оптимизации среды C# то будет зависеть от того в каком контексте вы используете эти данные, если просто в стеке их хранить то может и одно и тоже даже место занимать будут, если массив, то `byte` поменьше будет. Но это ориентировочно, так как оптимизация внутри среды C# может вести себя по-разному на разных платформах, и там не всё документировано.

Но в реальных приложениях, где не нужно выжимать максимум, обычно используется `enum` для хранения варианта из списка значений, который по умолчанию хранится в памяти как `int`, но можно настроить и другие варианты хранения, например `byte`, [описание тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum).
На уровне процессора думаю по скорости скорее всего будет одно и тоже. Но по удобству `enum` однозначно лучше, так как предоставляет интерфейс для работы с перечислениями.

**Добавлено:** Перечитал ваш вопрос ещё раз, и понял что у вас в игре эта переменная скорее всего будет один раз храниться, значит по скорости и по объёму памяти разницы не будет никакой. Если только вы не делаете базу результатов матча. Поэтому `enum`.

Comment: Скорее всё же UTF-16, а не Unicode, потому что все символы Юникода в 16 бит не уместятся.

Comment: Я отсюда взял - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин там же указано `Символ Юникода (16-разрядный)` что означает `UTF-16` :)

Comment: Отредактировал текст для точности. UTF - Unicode Transformation Format.

Comment: Поправка: enum можно и как byte хранить.

Comment: Знаю. Там разными типами можно, но я подумал что это тут роли не играет... Но могу добавить в текст... Int это то как он хранит данные по умолчанию.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на эту информацию.

Answer (score 10):

Первое правило любых оптимизаций: сначала померяй, потом оптимизируй.

Нет, не так: сначала померяй, потом подумай, а потом уже оптимизируй.

И снова не так: сначала померяй на **реальных сценариях с реальными данными**, потом подумай, потом попробуй свою оптимизацию, после чего проверь, что изменения играют роль в **реальных сценариях с реальными данными** и только потом окончательно принимай решение о необходимости той или иной оптимизации.

Теперь к вопросу. Точнее, к ответу:

Нужно использовать enum, поскольку он максимально подходит для перечисления нескольких элементов:

```
public enum GameState { Play, Lose, Win }
```

По умолчанию, размер экземпляра этого перечисления будет 4 байта. Но это можно поправить:

```
public enum GameState:byte { Play, Lose, Win }
```

Но здесь не все так просто (именно поэтому вначале нужно замерять в реальных условиях).

```
public class SomeClass
{
   private GameState _state;
   private string _name;
}
```

В этом случае размер `SomeClass` будет (64 разрядный .NET): ObjectHeader (16bytes) + 16 bytes. Поскольку будет выравнивание. На 32-х разрядном .NET-е будет 8 + 8.

Тут можно узнать о том, что наш `GameState` можно положить в структуру и использовать `Pack=1`, чтобы размер структуры был меньше. Но, почти наверняка это будет экономия на спичках только если число подобных объектов не будет исчисляться миллионами. Но даже если таких объектов миллионы, подобные трюки могут дать просед в скорости исполнения, поскольку доступ к невыровненным полям менее эффективен.

В общем, в качестве заключения: использовать enum, поскольку это то, что разумнее всего использовать для решения этой задачи. И забыть о производительности до тех пор, пока это не станет проблемой и не будет доказано с помощью профайлера.